# Why must you define the scanner inside the if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

Why does the code below work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WholeNumber
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        if (scanner.hasNextInt())
        {
            float number = scanner.nextFloat(); //The if statement is testing THIS scanner value.
            System.out.println("The number you entered is an integer.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The number you entered is not an integer.");
        }
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WholeNumber
{


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        float number = scanner.nextFloat(); //But when I put the scanner out here, it doesn't work??
        if (scanner.hasNextInt())
        {
            System.out.println("The number you entered is an integer.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The number you entered is not an integer.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

It would seem like you would have to define the scanner first so the *if* statement could know what it was checking. Otherwise, how does it know what it is trying to check?

When I put the scanner.nextFloat line outside the *if* statement, though, it will compile but get stuck during run-time when the user is typing in input. And if I put the line outside and change the *if* statement to "number.hasNextInt," I get a compile-time error.

Comment: Might want to make up your mind about `int` vs. `float`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the value out of the `Scanner` before you are testing for the next int:

```
 float year = scanner.nextFloat();
```

The above line removes the `int` from the `Scanner` so `hasNextInt()` will return `false`.

Side note: Not sure why you are using `hasNextInt()` with `nextFloat()` you should be using `Float` or `Int`...

Answer (score 1):

If the "has"-call is after the "next"-call, the scanner will wait for 2 values.

This is because `next___()` waits for a value, consumes it, AND then returns it, while `has___()` waits for a value, pushes it back, AND then returns the presence of it.

Comment: Ohh, I was under the impression that the "float number = scanner.nextFloat();" was what paused the program and caused it to wait for input. I didn't realize it was the "System.out.println("Please enter a number:");" statement that caused it to wait for an input.

Comment: Also, I think all the has____() methods return boolean. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ If you want to change that part, I'll accept your answer.